# Show that the alternating group $A_4$ has exactly 3 elements of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that the alternating group $A_4$ has exactly 3 elements of order 2. One can of course solve it by brute force (I have thus found that the elements of order 2 are $(12)(34), (13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$), but I would like to know if there is a more "neat" approach.

Comment: It can't contain elements of order $4$ (because a $4$-cycle is an odd permutation), and its $2$-Sylow subgroups have order $4$. Why can there be only one $2$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Unfortunately, there has been no mention of Sylow subgroups up to the part of the book where this exercise appears.

Comment: Hmm, then I don't know anything much neater than brute force. One can of course say that it contains $8$ elements of order $3$ ($\binom{4}{3}$ choices for the elements in the $3$-cycle, and for each set of $3$ elements $2$ cycles), and one element of order $1$, so that leaves $3$ elements for orders $2,\,4,\,6,\,12$. Only order $2$ can occur.

Comment: That's a nice argument! Why is it, however, immediate that there can be no element of order 4,6 or 12?

Comment: An element of order $4$ would be a product of a $4$-cycle with some disjoint cycles of order $2$ or $4$, and for the permutation to be even, you'd need an even number of factors. But you have only $4$ items to permute, so can't multiply a $4$-cycle with a disjoint cycle, thus no elements of order $4$. If there were an element of order $12$, the group would be cyclic, hence abelian. It isn't, so no element of order $12$. An element of order $6$ would contain a $6$-cycle, or a $3$-cycle and a disjoint $2$-cycle. But that would require at least $6$ resp. $3+2 = 5$ items to permute.

Comment: For $A_4$, that sort of reasoning doesn't pay, but for larger groups, it's quite fruitful.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: Once you know that elements of order $2$ are the product of two distinct cycles of length 2, you can use a simple method that it's useful to count elements of any given cycle structure. You want to fill in the number $1, 2, 3, 4$ into $(x y) (z w)$. You have 4 choices for $x$, then 3 for $y$, etc, so you get $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$. But of course the element does not change if you swap $x$ and $y$, so you divide by $2$. Ditto for $z$ and $w$, so divide once more by 2. Finally, you can also swap $(x y)$ and $(z w)$ without changing the element, so divide once more by 2. You get $24/8 = 3$.

Comment: @DanielFischer , can you clarify the argument in your first comment ? I mean , suppose we agreed that there is only a unique sylow 2-subgroup , how can you use this to prove the required ? also , I can't see the reason behind why is it necessary  that there is one 2-sylow subgroup ?

Comment: @FawzyHegab If there is only one $2$-Sylow subgroup, there are exactly three elements of order $2$ or $4$, since that subgroup has order $2^2$. $A_4$ contains no elements of order $4$, since a $4$-cycle is an odd permutation. And there is only one $2$-Sylow subgroup because there are too many elements of order $3$ for there to be more than one.

Comment: @DanielFischer , How can we know that there is to many elements of order 3 if there is more than one 2-sylow subgroup ? If there were more than one 2-sylow subgroup , the every non-identity element is an element of order 3(right?) , Is there any contradiction in that ?

Comment: @FawzyHegab You can see that $A_4$ contains eight elements of order $3$ directly, so there are only four spots left for elements of different orders, one is taken by the identity.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @DanielFischer :)  , the argument ( for me! ) can be written as follows , if there were more than one 2-sylow subgroup , then there exists 9 elements of order 2 ( as those 2-sylow subgroups are not cylic then they are isomorphic to $V_4$ ) and we know that there is 8 elements of order 3(easy to be proved )  , then $G$ has at least 9+8=17 element,contradiction! .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-trivial elements of $A_4$ are the $3$-cycles (which have order $3$) and the products of two disjoint transpositions (which have order $2$).